# Yii EOauth Twitter integration retrieve screen_name

Tags: php, twitter, yii, oauth

I have the twitter auth working, however I'm trying to return the user's screen name, there is a function called getName() that I'm trying to implement, however it always returns the TOKEN! I need help I have been struggling for weeks on this. The url is godj.nogole.com, click on requests and you will see.

```
 public function getName() {
$responseJson = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json ');

if ($responseJson) 
{
  $response = json_decode($responseJson);                   
  $name = $response[0]->screen_name;
}      

return name;

}
```

Comment: Is `return name;` a typo in the question or in your source as well? It ought to be `return $name;` afaik

Comment: J. David Smith: I fixed that error and still it only shows DJ Guest, it is not grabbing the twitter screen name.

Comment: Can you show the exact output of `file_get_contents`?